# push array into an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this snippet where I am trying to generate array of array of array of random numbers.

```
function generateRandomNumbers($pACount, $pBCount, $pCCount, $pDCount) {
    $points = array();
    $score = array();
    $res = array();
    $val = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $pACount; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j <= $pBCount; $i++) {
            for ($k = 0; $k <= $pCCount; $i++) {
                for ($l = 0; $l <= $pDCount; $i++) {
                    $points[] = rand(5, 95);
                }
                $score[] = $points;
            }
            $res[] = $score;
        }
        $val[] = $res;
    }
    return $val;
}
```

When I return this to AJAX it is returned as: `[[[[5, 32, 73, 62, 45]]]]`
which was suppose to be

```
[[[[5, 32, 73, 62, 45], [15, 2, 7, 6, 50]],[[25, 52, 93, 2, 5], [16, 32, 67, 63, 15]]]]
```

I am reletively very new to php coding(started a week back) and I have no clue here.
What am I missing?

Comment: It's usually better not to edit your question into the answer otherwise, other people visiting this page won't be able to understand what the problem was...

Comment: @Basic: Thanks for pointing it out. You guys are absolutely right!

Comment: Thanks to @hakre as well.. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `$i++` in every `for` loop, while it was supposed to be `$j++`, `$k++` and `$l++`.

### The corrected code

```
function generateRandomNumbers($pACount, $pBCount, $pCCount, $pDCount) {
    $points = array();
    $score = array();
    $res = array();
    $val = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $pACount; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j <= $pBCount; $j++) {
            for ($k = 0; $k <= $pCCount; $k++) {
                for ($l = 0; $l <= $pDCount; $l++) {
                    $points[] = rand(5, 95);
                }
                $score[] = $points;
            }
            $res[] = $score;
        }
        $val[] = $res;
    }
    return $val;
}
```